# normalize multi dimensional numpy array using the last value along axis 1

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following numpy array :

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],
             [15,25,35,45,55]])
```

I would like to create a new array with the same shape by dividing each dimension by the last element of the dimension

The output desired would be :

```
B = np.array([[0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1],
              [0.27272727,0.45454545,0.63636364,0.81818182,1]])
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this?

```
B = np.array([[A[i][j]/A[i][len(A[i])-1] for j in range(0,len(A[i]))] for i in range(0,len(A))])
```

Comment: @Romain sorry but this is a bad answer. You should never loop with numpy… [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71140189/16343464) is how you should do it with efficiency

Answer (score 3):

Slice the last element while keeping the dimensions and divide:

```
B = A/A[:,[-1]]  # slice with [] to keep the dimensions
```

or, better, to avoid an unnecessary copy:

```
B = A/A[:,-1,None]
```

output:

```
array([[0.2       , 0.4       , 0.6       , 0.8       , 1.        ],
       [0.27272727, 0.45454545, 0.63636364, 0.81818182, 1.        ]])
```

Comment: Nice and clever answer, I have added something faster on top of it ;)

Comment: This should really be `A / A[:, -1, None]` to avoid a copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using:

`[list(map(lambda i: i / a[-1], a)) for a in A]`

Result:

`[[0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0], [0.2727272727272727, 0.45454545454545453, 0.6363636363636364, 0.8181818181818182, 1.0]]`

Answer (score 0):

Adding on @mozway answer, it seems to be faster to take the last column and then add an axis with:

```py
B = A/A[:,-1][:,None]
```

for instance.

See the benchmark:
[image]

Comment: I think this is only faster on very small arrays (and thus I would say better keep the cleanest syntax). There shouldn't be significant difference on large arrays

Comment: Just tested on `A = np.random.random(size=(100, 10000))` and got `900 µs ± 16.5 µs per loop` for `[:,[-1]]` and `913 µs ± 40.7 µs per loop` for the `[:,-1][:,None]`

Comment: I just tested your size and got 763us vs 753us, it seems to be within the uncertainty bars.

Comment: precisely my point ;) I don't think `[:,-1][:,None]` is more explicit, so better stick to `[:, [-1]]`

Comment: Except if you are dealing with a small enough array and care about speed

Comment: Using advanced indexing ([-1]), will create a copy, this method will create an intermediate array, although will not copy the memory.  Best of both worlds is `A[:, -1, None]`, which will be a single indexing operation *and* avoid a copy.

Comment: @user3483203 I just tested your solution, it's indeed faster. Thanks for explaining why.